# how to retrieve data from list second list added to first

Tags: c#

I am having trouble displaying items from. a list.

I have a class `Doc` that has `Item`s. Then I am adding TextField to Item but then when I try to retrieve it I get just the namespace. I don't have any properties in the result related to the `textField` such as text etc. Only related to the item class.

Can you advise what I am doing wrong I can see the `textFormField` in the result when I debug but I don't know how to access it?!

```cs
public class Doc 
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
    
public class Item
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public Input Input { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public Result<Doc, ErrorCodes> ReturnDataSample()
{
    var finalResult = new Result<Doc, Error>();
    Doc doc = new Doc();
    doc.Items = new List<Item>();

    TextFormField textFormField = new TextFormField();
    textFormField.Text = "TEST";
    textFormField.PageIndex = 1;


    doc.Items.Add(textFormField);
    finalResult.Result = doc;

    return finalResult;
}
```

Filtering data

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new Test();
        var data = t.ReturnDataSample();
        Console.WriteLine(data.Result.Items.Count);
        Console.WriteLine(data.Result.SourceProvider.ItemsRawData);
        var test = new TextFormField();

        foreach (var item in data.Result.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: It would be better to have `doc.Items = new List<Item>();` inside the constructor for `Doc`. That way the value `doc.Items` is never null. And make the `Items` property readonly.

Comment: Please include the definition of `TextFormField`

Comment: Also the definition of `Input`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of points here. `Item` needs to override the `.ToString()` method in order to have a built in way to convert the object into a string.

In addition, the list of items in `Doc` should be initialized in the constructor and the property be made read-only.

something like this:

```
public class Doc 
{
    public Doc() { Items = new List<Item>(); }
    public List<Item> Items { get; }
    public int Count => Items.Count;
    public void Add(string id, Input input)
        => Items.Add(new Item() { ID=id, Input=input });
}
    
public class Item
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public Input Input { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"ID={ID}, Input={Input}";
}
```

and the above can be used as

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var doc = new Doc();
        doc.Add("1001", new Input(...));
        doc.Add("1002", new Input(...));

        foreach (var item in doc.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Console.WriteLine(item); =>  Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
```

item.ToString() returns class name.
Add a method that returns desired output to Item class and call it in the WriteLine.  Instead you may also override ToString() of Item class.

Answer (score 0):

You should override "ToString" method in "Item" class. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method

> Default implementations of the Object.ToString method return the fully qualified name of the object's type.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-5.0